# Using Microsoft Graph to update Applications passwordCredentials using addpassword method

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm changing my Powershell script that updates an applications passwordCredentials (specifically the keyId,secretText and Hint) as previously we used PATCH but this has now changed as per : https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/blogs/breaking-changes-application-and-serviceprincipal-api-updates-in-microsoft-graph-beta/

However when I use POST I cannot seem to update the KeyId, secretText and Hint anymore,  this continues to work with PATCH but was looking to update my code before this goes live,  can you assist?

This Code still works at present :

```
$jsonData = '
{
 "passwordCredentials": [
  {
  "customKeyIdentifier": null,
  "endDateTime": "2119-05-01T10:18:33.4995826Z",
  "keyId": "'+ $($guid) +'",
  "startDateTime": "2019-05-01T10:18:33.4995826Z",
  "secretText": "'+ $($Password.Password) +'",
  "hint": "'+ $($Passwordhint) +'"
  }
 ]
}'

#Specify the URI to call and method
$uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications/$ID/"
$method = "PATCH"
Invoke-WebRequest -Method $method -Uri $uri -ContentType "application/json" -Body $jsonData -Headers @{Authorization = "$($global:authtoken.authorization)"} -ErrorAction Stop | Out-Null
```

The following does POST but creates a password with none of the information provided,  passwordCredentials are not updated for the application as expected:

```
#Populate JSON data for the application
$jsonData = '
{
 "passwordCredentials": [
  {
  "customKeyIdentifier": null,
  "endDateTime": "2119-05-01T10:18:33.4995826Z",
  "keyId": "'+ $($guid) +'",
  "startDateTime": "2019-05-01T10:18:33.4995826Z",
  "secretText": "'+ $($Password.Password) +'",
  "hint": "'+ $($Passwordhint) +'"
  }
 ]
}'

#Specify the URI to call and method
$uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications/$ID/addPassword"
$method = "POST"
Invoke-WebRequest -Method $method -Uri $uri -ContentType "application/json" -Body $jsonData -Headers @{Authorization = "$($global:authtoken.authorization)"} -ErrorAction Stop | Out-Null
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears the `addPassword` action from https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata has a wrapped `passwordCredential` as a parameter:

```
...
<Action Name="addPassword" IsBound="true">
<Parameter Name="bindingParameter" Type="microsoft.graph.application" Nullable="false"/>
<Parameter Name="passwordCredential" Type="microsoft.graph.passwordCredential"/>
<ReturnType Type="microsoft.graph.passwordCredential" Nullable="false"/>
</Action>
...
```

A POST body like this:

```
{
  "passwordCredential": {
    "customKeyIdentifier": null,
    "endDateTime": "2119-05-01T10:18:33.4995826Z",
    "startDateTime": "2019-05-01T10:18:33.4995826Z",
    "displayName": "new test password"
  }
}
```

should return a generated credential like:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#microsoft.graph.passwordCredential",
    "customKeyIdentifier": null,
    "endDateTime": "2119-05-01T10:18:33.4995826Z",
    "keyId": "...",
    "startDateTime": "2019-05-01T10:18:33.4995826Z",
    "secretText": "...",
    "hint": "...",
    "displayName": "new test password"
}
```

Comment: Thank you however I would like to know how I can add/modify the keyID / SecretText and hint after Microsoft removes the ability to PATCH passwordCredentials,  will this be possible?

Comment: From the [post](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/blogs/breaking-changes-application-and-serviceprincipal-api-updates-in-microsoft-graph-beta/) you mentioned, it looks like a removePassword will be added. This should enable you to add the new and then remove the old password.